# React render no refresca mi componente flag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, icons

No me gustan las (múltiples) formas que tiene React de traducir páginas, por lo que me he creado mi propia solución. Junto con esa solución he creado un componente que me muestra la bandera del idioma.

Como se puede observar cuando se invoca el objeto App desde index.js paso un prop llamado 'language' donde se especifica qué lenguage debe ser cargado.

Si se observa, en appjs, se carga perfectamente el primer prop y lo muestra perfectamente, pero cuando cambio de idioma, a pesar de estar relacionado con el state lang, no refresca el icono.

Alguna ayuda?
Gracias de antemano

en index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App language='en'/>, document.getElementById('root'));


serviceWorker.unregister();
```

en App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Flag from './components/Flag'
import english from './language/en.json'
import spanish from './language/es.json'

export default class App extends Component {

  state = {
    language : ''
  }

  langConstants = {
    en: english,
    es: spanish
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      language: props.language
    }

    this.locale = this.langConstants[this.state.language]
  }

  componentDidMount()
  {
    this.changeLanguage('es')
  }

  changeLanguage = lang => {
    this.setState({language : lang})
    this.locale = this.langConstants[lang]
  }



  render() {    
    console.log(this.state)
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.locale.welcome}, lang '{this.state.language}': <Flag flag={this.state.language} />
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

en language/en.js

```
{
  "welcome" : "Welcome"
}
```

en language/es.js

```
{
  "welcome" : "Bienvenido"
}
```

y en components/Flag.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import 'flag-icon-css/css/flag-icon.css'

export default class Flag extends Component {

  state = {
    flag : ''
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = ({
      flag: (props.flag === 'en') ? 'gb' : props.flag
    })
  }

  render() {
    const flag = `flag-icon flag-icon-${this.state.flag}`
    return (
      <span className={flag}></span>
    )
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Le estas pasando al componente *App* por props 'en', lo guardas en el estado dentro del constructor. Con lo que debería usarse en un primer momento, pero seguidamente al render en `componentDidMount()` haces una llamada para guardar en el estado 'es', esto vuelve a ejecutar el render() de forma automática y solo deberías ver la bandera asociada al 'es' si esta todo bien, no veo como puedes cambiarla sin ningún evento.

Puedes hacer un `console.log` dentro de `render()` para ver que idioma le pasas al componente `Flag`:

```
render() {
   console.log('LANG: ' + this.state.flag);
    const flag = `flag-icon flag-icon-${this.state.flag}`
    return (
      <span className={flag}></span>
    )
  }
```

Ten en cuenta que al setear el estado en el constructor, esto se hace al inicio y solo una vez, y si lo haces en `componentDidMount()` tambien lo hace solo una vez, después del primer `render()`, que en este caso es tan rápido que no vas ni a verlo.

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente, se necesitaba ejecutar el método estático getDerivedStateFromProps en el componente Flag.js, que queda así:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import 'flag-icon-css/css/flag-icon.css'

export default class Flag extends Component {

  state = {
    flag : ''
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = ({
      flag: (props.flag === 'en') ? 'gb' : props.flag
    })
  }


  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props,state) {
    if( props.flag !== state.flag) {
      return {
        flag: (props.flag === 'en') ? 'gb' : props.flag
      }
    }
    return null
  }

  render() {
    const flag = `flag-icon flag-icon-${this.state.flag}`
    return (
      <span className={flag}></span>
    )
  }

}
```